# How to translate an ElasticSearch multimatch search query from cURL into JAVA?

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch

So, having made up the (right) query in ES and tested it against a local ES installation using the sense plugin, I am now facing the problem: How to do the same from my code using the ES JAVA API. Here is the query I am trying to translate:

```
{
"size": 5,
"query": {
  "multi_match": {
     "query": "physics",
     "type": "most_fields",
     "fields": [
         "document.title^10",
         "document.title.shingles^2",
         "document.title.ngrams",
         "person.name^10",
         "person.name.shingles^2",
         "person.name.ngrams",
         "document.topics.name^10",
         "document.topics.name.shingles^2",
         "document.topics.name.ngrams"
      ],
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}'
```

I know it should be something like this, but I am not quite sure:

```
 Node node = nodeBuilder().client(true).node();
    Client client = node.client();

    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("dlsnew")
            .setTypes("person", "document")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("physics",
                    "document.title^10",
                    "document.title.shingles^2",
                    "document.title.ngrams",
                    "person.name^10",
                    "person.name.shingles^2",
                    "person.name.ngrams",
                    "document.topics.name^10",
                    "document.topics.name.shingles^2",
                    "document.topics.name.ngrams"))
            .setFrom(0).setSize(5).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
```

Also, how to handle the "operator" and "type":"most_fields" parts from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("physics",
                "document.title^10",
                "document.title.shingles^2",
                "document.title.ngrams",
                "person.name^10",
                "person.name.shingles^2",
                "person.name.ngrams",
                "document.topics.name^10",
                "document.topics.name.shingles^2",
                "document.topics.name.ngrams")
                .operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND)
                .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.MOST_FIELDS);
```